# Will there be impact on accessing a static URL for item on Google drive from a published addon after 13th September security update

Tags: google-drive-api

Impact from security update coming on 13th September -

1. We have a Google addin that is published on Google Marketplace. Will there be any impact on using it?
2. We are having a logo URL which is a static URL used to access an image on google drive, will there be any impact on accessing it from the published addin?
3. How to check Drive API permission for a URL?

Answer (score 0):

2. May be yes.. because the logo that was embed on is a public url, and it should need resourceKey if the security update on 13 Sep is applied.

https://support.google.com/drive/thread/118976647/why-google-update-to-some-google-drive-file-links-with-resource-key?hl=en

Comment: Is there any way to test it before update that it will work or not?

Comment: Wait until that update implemented to know more